How I can download stories from telegram using telethon?
I have simple telethon script, that gives me info about all telegram stories, that have's on my chats and try to download it, but print(download) return "None". How I can download this stories (not only telethon, I can use some other library)?
from telethon import TelegramClient, functions
import asyncio

api_id = ###
api_hash = ###

async def fetch_stories():
    async with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        result = await client(functions.stories.GetAllStoriesRequest())
        print(result.stringify())

        downloaded = await client.download_media(result.peer_stories)
        print(downloaded)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(fetch_stories())

Don't found info about it in telethon docs and google
